# jQuery add .css() if input value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of dynamic inputs and want to add css of parent element if a value entered is higher then 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).prev('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
      }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).next('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
      }
    });
  });

  $('document').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
    };
  });

  if ($('input').val() !== 0) {
    $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 100%;
}

.roomWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputBox {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 20px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.inputBox laber {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.inputInner {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.inputInner a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: ;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="sofa">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="sofa" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="table">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="table" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="piano">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="piano" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

But I can't make it work. Could you please suggest what's wrong?

Here's the whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/dr7z7tkf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger the change event while clicking on the  `+` and `-` .Parse the input value on change event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).prev('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
      }
      $('input').trigger('change')
    });
    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).next('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
      }
            $('input').trigger('change')
    });
  });

  $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
      $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
    }else{
      $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '0.2');
    }
  });
  if ($('input').val() !== 0) {
    $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
  };

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 100%;
}

.roomWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputBox {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 20px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.inputBox laber {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.inputInner {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.inputInner a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: ;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roomWrap">

  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="bookshelf">Bookshelf<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="bookshelf"  value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="sofa">Sofa<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="sofa" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="love seat">Love seat<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="love seat" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="lamp">Lamp<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="lamp" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="book-box">Book box<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="book-box" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="armoir">Armoir<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="armoir" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="grand-piano">Grand piano<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="grand-piano" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="upright-piano">Upright piano<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="upright-piano" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="TV">TV<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="TV" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="TV-stand">TV stand<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="TV-stand" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="coffee-table">Coffee table<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="coffee-table" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="desk">Desk<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="desk" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="lamp">Lamp<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="lamp" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="plant">Plant<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="plant" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="mirror">Mirror<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="mirror" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label for="picture">Picture<span class="inputInner"><a class="minus">-</a><input name="picture" value="0"><a class="plus">+</a></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('input').trigger('change')` wont it trigger change to all `input` in dom tree!!

Comment: @ShekharPankaj yes.But for this case  inside the change event, he was calling `this` that means targeted only the nested and closest element, not for all

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you need you should trigger a `change` event on the `input` after updating its value.

You also need to change `$('document')` to `$(document)`. There's also no need for nested document.ready event handlers, as you can place all logic within a single one.

Finally, you can both DRY up and improve the logic by using a single click handler on the incrementing `a` elements, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.plus, .minus').on('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.siblings('input').val(function(i, v) {
      var newV = (parseInt(v, 10) || 0) + $btn.data('inc');
      return newV >= 0 ? newV : v;
    }).change();
  });

  $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    $(this).closest('.inputBox').toggleClass('foo', parseInt(this.value, 10) > 0);
  }).change();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 100%;
}

.roomWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputBox {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 20px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.inputBox laber {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.inputInner {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.inputInner a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: ;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.foo {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="sofa">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a href="#" data-inc="-1" class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="sofa" value="0">
      <a href="#" data-inc="1" class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="table">
    Table
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a href="#" data-inc="-1" class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="table" value="0">
      <a href="#" data-inc="1" class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="piano">
    Piano
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a href="#" data-inc="-1" class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="piano" value="0">
      <a href="#" data-inc="1" class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the javascript to this and try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).prev('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        $qty.closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
      }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).next('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I don't really know why your code didn't work, because I saw a design problem at first sight. It was this: you made the onclick function, and then an onchange function. But, isn't it true that if you click the + or the - button you're also changing the value? So, I just put the function that changed the opacity (`$qty.closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');`) inside of the function executed when you click the + button.

Comment: Can you please mention what changes you have made ?

Comment: Yes! updating in a minute

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value programatically, the `change` event never fires, you have to trigger it manually when you click the buttons, and change the value

```
$qty.val(currentVal + 1).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dr7z7tkf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

$qty.trigger('change') and secure the input event $(document).on('input change')

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).prev('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        $qty.trigger('change');
      }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
      var $qty = $(this).next('input');
      var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
        $qty.trigger('change');
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('input change', 'input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
    };
  });

  if ($('input').val() !== 0) {
    $(this).closest('.inputBox').css('opacity', '1');
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 100%;
}

.roomWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputBox {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 22px 0px 22px 20px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.inputBox laber {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.inputInner {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.inputInner a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.8vw;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: ;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="sofa">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="sofa" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="table">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="table" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="inputBox">
  <label for="piano">
    Sofa
    <span class="inputInner">
      <a class="minus">-</a>
      <input name="piano" value="0">
      <a class="plus">+</a>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```